# Vertical menu in Activity page uses too much horizontal space

Tags: discussion, design, activity-tab

A recent change in the layout of the Activity page produces suboptimal page layout:

- the horizontal menu probably had some issues on narrow devices such as smartphones and the switch to a dropdown is a good solution for those,
- yet on desktop the vertical submenu reduces the available horizontal space for the actual information: an undesirable side-effect which makes the page layout less efficient and IMHO less readable and less elegant.

It is possible to revert to a horizontal submenu if enough horizontal space is available?

If you are looking for some real savings in the page layout, you could get rid of the left navigation completely. I would be surprised if the click rate on this area from actual users is anything but infinitesimal. Thankfully this panel can be hidden in settings, but is it used at all?

Comment: Which “left panel”? Left navigation can be hidden in the [settings](//stackoverflow.com/users/preferences). This issue has already been reported by [Vikki](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/372653/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon: OK, too bad this customisation is not more obvious by default. I updated the question

Comment: There's a huge list of bugs on this [MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page) which is quite active since the change and seems to be the official bug tracker for this feature

Comment: @charlietfl: OK. I might delete this question